# Limits which involve an explicit $0$

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis, indeterminate-forms

I am trying to solve the following limit (or prove it doesn't exist)

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^2}{||x,y||} $$

where $(x, y) \in R^2$.

I decided to analyze the limit over the y-axis, and reached the following expression

$$ \lim \frac{0}{|y|} $$

and I don't know what to do. Is this $0$, or an indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$? Should this be an indeterminate form, how do I proceed?

Is there an easier form to solve the previous limit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it is not indeterminate, for all $y\ne0$, $\frac 0{|y|}=0$ has the limit $0$.

Comment: In the expression $\lim_{y \to 0}f(y)$ , y never reaches 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$||x,y||=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
And,
$$0\le x^2\le x^2+y^2$$
$$0\le \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
$$ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}0\le\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^2}{||x,y||} \le \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
$$0\le \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^2}{||x,y||}\le 0$$
$$\Rightarrow  \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^2}{||x,y||} = 0$$

For the other part of the question,
$$\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{0}{|y|} = \lim_{y \rightarrow 0}0=0$$

This is because as per the definition of a limit, we can have $y$ arbitrarily close to $0$ but $y\ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the generalized squeeze theorem:

$$0\le\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2}}=\frac{x^2}{|x|}=\pm x\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}0$$